# Xcode 5.0.2 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest

Tags: xcode, dyld, xctest

I have problems running a project in Xcode 5.0.2

I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest
  Referenced from: /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/relatio-cwlmozvklaldmictbbjthzuoxnxz/Build/Products/Debug/relatio.app/Contents/MacOS/relatio
```

Reason: image not found
(lldb)

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: This is how I solved the problem:

1. Navigate to the project's "Build Settings"
2. Search for "Runpath Search Paths"
3. Enter the following path in the column below the product name:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/

Comment: You can answer your own question by writing an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 28):

It looks like your main target is linking to XCTest.framework as well as your test target. It should only be linked to the main target.

1) Go to Project settings

2) Go to your apps main target -> other linker flags

3) remove '-framework XCTest'

4) make sure the 'other linker flags' field for your test target still contains '-framework XCTest'

Comment: I followd this. but not helped

Comment: Good answer, but what I have there is `$(inherited)` to bring in the data from CocoaPods.

Comment: Instead of removing, you can also make your framework optional by doing **-weak_framework "XCTest"**

Comment: I don't have test target anymore, I've removed it from the app. Still I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into this error by renaming my targets one of which was a testing target. After reading the other answers I realized that my Build Phases > Compile Sources *was including test classes as compile sources* for non-test targets which then tried to import the XCTest framework.

Removing the test classes from my regular target’s Compile Sources solved this for my case.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem this way.
I have edited scheme, at "Build" tab ticked "Run".

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that, according to the dyld error message you posted, your *application* is linking against XCTest.framework. That's incorrect; only your test bundle needs to link against XCTest.framework since only your test bundle contains tests.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem with OCMock library and solution is:

```
target :"Application Tests", :exclusive => true do
    pod 'OCMock'
end
```

Comment: For those dummies like me, if your application is named MyApp, the target here is MyAppTests ...

Comment: Careful, if you do 'exclusive => true'  you are NOT including any more pods from other targets.

Comment: Note that :exclusive has since been replaced with `inherit! :search_paths`. See http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0-Migration-Guide/

Comment: @LeszekZarna Sure, I added the post 1.0 syntax to your existing example.

Answer (score 5):

In my case It was RxTests added by Swift Package Manager to main application target. In pods you decide which Rx components add to which target, but SPM adds it all to main target as default.

Comment: Yes I removed from the main target and it works fine now. Thanks

Comment: I moved **RxTest** pod to test target in **Podfile** then deleted `Xcode Derived data`, then the problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved the problem:

1. Navigate to the project's "Build Settings"
2. Search for "Runpath Search Paths"
3. Enter the following path in the column below the product name: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/

Comment: This is incorrect in a couple of ways. First, it will lead to a dependency of your application on XCTedt.framework, which is only available within Xcode. Second, you're using an absolute path, which isn't guaranteed to be the same from Mac to Mac (for example if you have multiple versions of Xcode installed).

Comment: @ChrisHanson: This is really working with Xcode 5.1.1. But note that you don't need to provide Absolute Path, relative path should be provided. My scenario was, I have build Dynamic Frameworks with Xcode 6, then i tried to used it in Xcode 5.1.1 in my application, I received same issue describe here... I tried giving path of my Dynamic framework in "Runpath Search paths" and it worked..

Answer (score 2):

In my main Target's "Link Binary With Libraries" (under Build Phases), it was the testing framework I was using (Nimble.framework) that was causing the problem. Removed it, and everything's fine!

Answer (score 1):

enter the reference of your framework on framework search path AND 
Run path search path under "Build Settings"---...Now all set to invoke your projects by using import

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue is because i add a new file into the framework. So just run "`pod install`" solved my issue. But make sure your pod under `Tests` target too.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the ones that came up with the same issue:

Check on the lateral right menu which **has to look like that**:

[image: Should be]

And **has not have to look like that**:

[image: Shouldn't be]

Comment: You could probably explain that applies for all and only your test files.

Answer (score 0):

For our case, we want to use `Mockingjay` for both app target and test target

```
target 'MyProject' do
  pod 'Mockingjay/Core'
  # all pods that are not test go here

  target 'MyProjectTest' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      pod 'Mockingjay/XCTest'
      pod 'Quick', ' ~> 0.9.2'
      # .. all test pods go here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was changing your test target's [`inherit` attribute](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inherit_bang) in your Podfile from `:search_paths` to `:complete`.
Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56273013/1742518) suggests that `:search_paths` is designed for test environments.

```
target 'myapp' do    
  use_frameworks!

  target 'myappTests' do
    #inherit! :search_paths
    inherit! :complete
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error using ios-snapshot-test-case v5.0.2 via Carthage. The  problem is related to XCode 11. Apple renamed `libswiftXCTest.dylib` to `libXCTestSwiftSupport.dylib` and added `XCTest.swiftmodule` which has the same symbols in it and can work in place of the old one. But Apple forgot to tell iOS 11.x simulators about this change.

So you need to fix the older iOS version simulators. Here is the terminal command that fixed it for me:

```
sudo zsh -c ' sourcedir="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib"; 
targetdir="/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 11.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib"; 
ln -s $sourcedir/libXCTestSwiftSupport.dylib $targetdir/libswiftXCTest.dylib;
ln -s $sourcedir/XCTest.swiftmodule $targetdir/XCTest.swiftmodule'
```

See my comment here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9165#issuecomment-573523322

Answer (score 0):

Go to General > Targets (Left side).

You might have 2nd item containing the word test/s. Click it.

In this general settings > Testing >  Host application > Select from options (your app name). That's it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocoapods, double check that the `default_subspec` (which by omission includes all available subspecs) does not accidentaly bundle `XCTest`, e.g. For the following `.podspec`

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'MySpec'
  # ... spec definition details

  # "Normal" subspecs

  s.subspec 'NormalSubspec1' do |subspec|
      # ... subspec details
  end

  s.subspec 'NormalSubspec2' do |subspec|
      # ... subspec details
  end
  
  # Testing subspec

  s.subspec 'TestingSubspec' do |subspec|
      subspec.frameworks = 'XCTest'
      # ... subspec details
  end
end
```

if you were to depend on it in a `Podfile` as

```rb
target 'MyTarget' do
   pod 'MySpec'
end
```

it would include all subspecs (`MySpec/NormalSubspec1`, `MySpec/NormalSubspec2`, and `MySpec/TestingSubspec`).

Whereas, if you also define `default_subspec`, then you can exclude `MySpec/TestingSubspec` from the default dependency.

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'MySpec'
  # ... spec definition details

  s.default_subspec = 'NormalSubspec1', 'NormalSubspec2'

  # "Normal" subspecs

  s.subspec 'NormalSubspec1' do |subspec|
      # ... subspec details
  end

  s.subspec 'NormalSubspec2' do |subspec|
      # ... subspec details
  end
  
  # Testing subspec

  s.subspec 'TestingSubspec' do |subspec|
      # ... subspec details
      subspec.frameworks = 'XCTest'
  end
end
```

and it would now behave the same way as if you had explicity dependend on the subspecs

```rb
target 'MyTarget' do
   pod 'MySpec/NormalSubspec1'
   pod 'MySpec/NormalSubspec2'
end
```