# CocoaPods adds incorrect Other Linker Flags

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I placed `$(inherited)` in Other Linker Flags in the Build Settings of my app. Now, it's causing an error, but adding a Test framework.

The error and solution are explained in detail here: [Xcode 5.0.2 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340763/xcode-5-0-2-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-xctest-framework-versions-a-xctest)

How can I modify the Other Linker Flags added by CocoaPods to ensure the XCTests does not get added?

One solution would be if I can somehow copy all the actual values of `$(inherited)` and replace `$(inherited)` with those values, then just remove `XCTests` framework. However, I'm not sure how to find those.