# Xcode 6.1 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest error

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xctest

I imported my old project in **Xcode 6.1** and error mentioned above started coming during runtime, with reason  **image not found**,I have tried all off the answers suggested in following link

[Xcode 5.0.2 dyld error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340763/xcode-5-0-2-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-xctest-framework-versions-a-xctest)

but none of them worked for me so far,so does anybody have any idea how to get rid of this problem.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I resolved the issue,but i don't know whether it is the right answer in XCode 6 what i did is just set the flag optional for XCTest.framework in build phases under link binary with libraries

Answer (score 7):

This was used for **betfair/aping-ios-sdk**

1) Go to **Project settings** -> **App Main Target** -> **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary With Libraries** and make sure you have XCTest.frameworks in there

[image]

if not, click **+** button, then **Add Other** Framework

[image]

then press together **CMD + SHIFT + G** and enter

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks**

if you need it for simulator, you need to alter the path appropriately

[image]

press **ENTER** and select the **XCTest.framework**

2) now it is present in bundle just make it optional as seen in first image and you should be good to go

Comment: This worked for me. The important set is the to mark the framework optional. I did all the steps but keep the framework as required and keep getting the above error. After i changed to optional the build started working.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cocoapods you might need to do pod update, that worked for me

Comment: This isn't work for me. Please update your answer. I'm adding OCMock via cocoapod. Does it include itself with XCTest? Actually, I've zero idea about XCTest and OCMock. I'm running a client code which was created in 2012.