# Xcode 8.1 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest error

Tags: ios, uitest

So，this is the error,I record my UI script done,but the error occurred when I replayed the UI script.the console show :

"dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D093D58-4246-40F6-A1E5-9B51018453E5/UITest7UITests-Runner.app/XCTRunner
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D093D58-4246-40F6-A1E5-9B51018453E5/UITest7UITests-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D093D58-4246-40F6-A1E5-9B51018453E5/UITest7UITests-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D093D58-4246-40F6-A1E5-9B51018453E5/UITest7UITests-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6D093D58-4246-40F6-A1E5-9B51018453E5/UITest7UITests-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest'"

There is a same question:[Xcode 6.1 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691432/xcode-6-1-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-xctest-framework-xctest-error);
but my error can not be solved,and the message showed:

"ld: framework not found XCTest
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
But in this path he tolded I really can be found the framework named XCTest.framework

[image]

So what can I do,thanks very much!

Comment: any solution? i have same error

Comment: @AvinashVaghasiya Were you able to solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

If you used Cocoapods, i guess you add some Unit Test framework that includes `XCTest` as a dependency at `podfile`.

But this framework can only add to `TestTarget`. which like this:

```
target 'MyProjectTargetTest' do
   pod 'Kiwi'  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change Requared to Optional. Its help to me.