# What does inherit! :search_paths do?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

After looking at CocoaPods' own example (from https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#abstract_target)

```
# Note: There are no targets called "Shows" in any of this workspace's Xcode projects
abstract_target 'Shows' do
  pod 'ShowsKit'

  # The target ShowsiOS has its own copy of ShowsKit (inherited) + ShowWebAuth (added here)
  target 'ShowsiOS' do
    pod 'ShowWebAuth'
  end

  # The target ShowsTV has its own copy of ShowsKit (inherited) + ShowTVAuth (added here)
  target 'ShowsTV' do
    pod 'ShowTVAuth'
  end

  # Our tests target has its own copy of
  # our testing frameworks, and has access
  # to ShowsKit as well because it is
  # a child of the abstract target 'Shows'

  target 'ShowsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Specta'
    pod 'Expecta'
  end
end
```

I don't see why `inherit! :search_paths` is necessary? All 3 targets, `ShowsiOS`, `ShowsTV` and `ShowsTests` have access to `ShowsKit` from their parent target.

The specific example for `inherit!` (from https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inherit_bang) doesn't add any clarity

```
target 'App' do
  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

Can you help me understand what `inherit! :search_paths` is for?

Comment: did you get some clarity on why we use it since you posted the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: Seems that this is a functional that nobody ever use =)

Answer (score 38):

The purpose behind behind `inherit!`, according to https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inherit_bang
 (which I would agree is not very clear), is to provide one of 3 available modes:

- `:complete` The target inherits all behaviour from the parent.
- `:none` The target inherits none of the behaviour from the parent.
- `:search_paths` The target inherits the search paths of the parent only.

In this question's example it is the `:search_paths` mode that is being expressed. The three different modes serve different roles when testing a Pod project.

[Here is an additional link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html) pertaining to Framework Search Paths in Xcode that helped clear some confusion for me.

Answer (score 19):

**CocaPods and inherit!**

An **inner** target with dependency can use this functionality. The best example is `Test target` that uses `app target`. In this case you can create a hierarchy in your `Podfile`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218904/4770877)

```
target 'App' do
  target 'Tests' do
#    inherit! :none            # empty
#    inherit! :complete        # by default if you do not specify any inherit!
#    inherit! :search_paths    # uses only `search` paths 
  end
end
```

Take a look at generated `Pods/Targets Support Files/` directory and compare

```
Pods-<App_target_name>/Pods-<App_target_name>.<debug/release>.xcconfig
Pods-<Test_target_name>/Pods-<Test_target_name>.<debug/release>.xcconfig
```

You will find that settings which are passed to to the project's target[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877) are different for different `inherit!` setting.

In case with `inherit! :search_paths` - `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`, `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`... of inner target were inherited from outer target and were passed to the corresponding fields in `Build Settings`

Use case of `inherit! :complete`. When you develop a framework that has a third-party dynamic framework and you have a test target. If you do not do this and run tests you will get `dyld: Library not loaded`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216661/4770877)