# Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

My project can normally work in the past, but now it suddenly crashes when runs for a while. 
Error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/qizijia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7CDDEA9B-0ADD-4A64-8084-BCFBBDF40483/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FE1EC391-A6B7-44F7-AEDE-DB643B125DBB/ppp.app/Frameworks/CircleMenu.framework/CircleMenu
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
```

I have tried to follow the answers according to [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986082/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftswiftononesupport-dylib),but it didn't help.

Comment: Try this: Delete `Derived Data`. Kill the simulator. Restart XCode 10 (?) and clean the project. Maybe try on a hardware device.

Comment: https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2018/12/05/rpath-what/
See if this article helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport" Framework Target's build Phases
2. Click on + button on upper right corner and select " New Run Script Phase"
3. Add the Following Script and then run the project.

```
cd $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR
mkdir $PROJECT_NAME.framework/Frameworks &>/dev/null
for framework in *.framework; do
if [ $framework != $PROJECT_NAME.framework ]; then
cp -r $framework $PROJECT_NAME.framework/Frameworks/ &>/dev/null
fi
done
```